# Using VHost naming for staging, api subdomains

Tags: ssl, dns, digital-ocean, dokku, lets-encrypt

I want to have my main app accessable at `mydomain.com`

From here I also want `api.mydomain.com` and `staging.mydomain.com`

I use DigitalOcean and Dokku, along with letsencrypt SSL

I have now sat up my main app at `production.mydomain.com`, can i redirect visitors to `mydomain.com`, from here?

How is this achievable?

Comment: This is not related to programming.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you add your domain (e.g. `example.com`) to your app:

```
dokku domains:add yourappname example.com
```

Then in your app you can issue a redirect when people access it via `production.example.com`:

```
// ExpressJS
res.redirect(302, 'https://example.com');
```